# Facebook Ads, possible to add dynamic parameters in URL for FB to populate later?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I need to add ad_group id to ad's URL. However, I can only obtain the id after creating the ad, not before. Is it possible for me to specify a parameter in the URL so that it can be populated by FB when the ad is created? I know double click of Google supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to automatically add the adgroup ID to the referral params of an adgroup - typically developers use their own system's reference for tracking purposes in the url tags, or add the creative ID, something like that

Answer (score 3):

A solution has been released recently:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/new-facebook-ads-url-dynamic-parameters-trishan-naidoo/

> Dynamic Parameters & Values
>
> There are currently 8 parameters that can be dynamically inserted into ad URLs:
>
> **Site Source Name [site_source_name]** - This parameter has 4 possible values depending on whether the ad appeared on Facebook ('fb'), Instagram ('ig'), Messenger ('msg') or the Audience Network ('an'). Note: Facebook's help documentation incorrectly lists {{site_source_name}} as the dynamic parameter but my testing shows that it only works with square brackets.
>
> **Placement {{placement}}** - This parameter has 6 possible values depending on whether the ad appeared on the desktop feed, mobile feed or the right column on Facebook, the Messenger inbox or within the Instagram Feed or Instagram Stories.
>
> **Campaign, Ad Set & Ad Names {{campaign.name}} {{adset.name}} {{ad.name}}** - This parameter will dynamically insert the name of the campaign, ad set or ad according to how you have named each when setting up ads.
>
> **Campaign, Ad Set & Ad IDs {{campaign.id}} {{adset.id}} {{ad.id}}** - This parameter will dynamically insert the automatically assigned ID of the campaign, ad set or ad. To find out IDs, you will need to customise your columns to add the relevant ID column.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing this incorrectly. When setting up my ad in facebook, I set the optional URL parameters as (without quotes): "utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=facebook_display_ad&utm_campaign=facebook_id_test&utm_content={{ad.id}}"  , but when I check in google analytics and see the traffic from this ad, I find that the ad ID is not populated and shows up exactly as {{ad.id}} . Is this working properly for anybody else? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMione - yes, this works well for me. In Analytics, you will get some {{ad.id}} entries, mainly from FB's review team testing the URL. But live ads will replace the ad.id with the ad's id. How are you attempting to view the ad stats in Analytics? What report are you using? Try adding a secondary dimension for ad content.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Facebook has recently published a list of dynamic parameters that will be populated in your URL's. 
The list is available on their [site](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes